# has_many "not something" :through. What conditions should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User, Game and GameView. GameView describe what games users have seen. Trouble is I can't figure out what conditions should I use to fetch unviewed games.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_views
  has_many :unviewed_games, :through => :game_views, :source => :game, ???what conditions???
end

class GameView < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this as an association because an association is generally something where you have a foreign key pointing to something, but in this case you have no foreign key.  I see this as more of an instance attribute which I would do like this:

```
def unviewed_games
  Game.all(:conditions => ["id NOT IN (SELECT game_id FROM game_views WHERE user_id = ?", self.id])
end
```

You could do a `NOT IN (1,2,3)` by querying the viewed games, but that can get very inefficient, very very fast.  This is one time I would write out the SQL.  I would also do one more thing:

```
def unviewed_games
  return @unviewed_games if defined(@unviewed_games)
  @unviewed_games = Game.all(:conditions => ["id NOT IN (SELECT game_id FROM game_views WHERE user_id = ?", self.id])
end
```

That will store it in an instance variable for the length of the request, and save you the multiple database hits.  You can do `||=`, but if somehow you were to get a `nil`, then you would still query the database multiple times.  Rails should cache, but call me paranoid.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. No need to add the `:include` clause to the query. I would remove the declaration check line also, i.e. `@unviewed_games ||= Game.all(...`

Comment: good call about the `:include`, I had changed the query when I was writing the post.  Leaving the declaration line, just because the `||=` can still requery the database if a nil return - shouldn't happen on a `.all`, but I like my code to be consistent.  This way I always have the declaration check instead of sometimes `||=` and sometimes a declaration check.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you has_many :viewed_games and write a separate method to collect unviewed games? I'd be hesitant to put any more logic in a has_many.

Answer (score 0):

You can't express a relationship this way in Rails using `has_many :through` (or at least not to my knowledge). But you can create a named scope based on `:game_views` to retrieve the desired objects.

I believe this will do the trick (not tested):

`named_scope :unviewed_games, :joins => 'LEFT JOIN game_views ON game_views.game_id = games.id', :conditions => 'game_view_id IS NULL')`